# Adding image to MFMessageViewController works fine in IOS5 but not in IOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, ios6

I have got a strange issue , the below code works fine in IOS5 device , all simulators , but fails in IOS6 Device.I am getting a blank view in place of image.

Requirement : Need to add the image in mail.

```
NSString *imageName = @"classroom_tile.png"; 
imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]bundlePath];
imagePath = [imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageName]];
imagePath = [@"file:///" stringByAppendingString:imagePath];

NSString *formatedUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"</br><table border =\"0\"><tr><td></td><th>%@</th></tr><tr><td><img src= \'%@\' width=200 height=150></td></tr></table>",sometext,imagePath];
[mailComposer setMessageBody:formatedUrl isHTML:YES];
```

Please do suggest.

Thanks and Regards,
Anil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do has never been supported. The only valid way to get an image into an email is to add the image as an attachment. But even then you can't reference the image attachment in the mail message body.

What works in the simulator is irrelevant for something like this since you can't actually send the email in the simulator. Let me ask this - when running this on an iOS 5 device, does the received email sent from the app actually show the image or does it only appear correctly in the mail composer in the app? I'd be quite surprised if such an email sent from the app and opened in some email client on a user's computer showed the image.

Edit: It turns out this really did work under iOS 5 but doesn't under iOS 6. I'm quite surprised. I did my own quick test. Under iOS 5.1 sending an email with such an image reference to a local file on the iOS device actually does get sent along with the email and does appear in the client email program on their computer. When the app is run under iOS 6, the image does not appear in the mail composer in the app nor in the received email. So at least that is consistent.

One other little side note. This line:

```
imagePath = [imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageName]];
```

should be:

```
imagePath = [imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
```

Don't use `stringWithFormat:` unless you are actually using a string format. Also, there is no need to create the extra `NSString` object.

Also, here's a better way to get the path to a file in your resource bundle:

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"classroom_tile" ofType:@"png"];
```

That one line would replace the first three lines you posted.

One last note. When using an HTML email message, include the `<html>` and `<body>` tags.

Comment: Hi rmaddy,thanks for the reply. Image will be showed in email and the same image will appear when u send a mail.And even the receiver will have the same image.Also this is working fine in IOS5 but not in IOS6.Also I have tried replace to single line as you mentioned but it didn't help me.

Comment: I am curious - what has been your experience actually sending such an email under iOS 5? Did the received email have the image or not?

Comment: Wow - I never would have thought that would work. I'll have to try it.

Comment: @IamAnil I updated my answer to reflect that this did work under iOS 5 but doesn't under iOS 6. Very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is not possible with the current MessageUI API: the MSMessageComposeViewController doesn't accept attachments like the MFMailComposeViewController does.

The only way to do this currently is to use an external service that allows you to send mms via a REST call for example.

GSMA defines a REST specification for exactly this purpose:     http://www.gsmworld.com/oneapi/reference_documentation-version_1.html (multiple pdf's on this page)

Try to find a local service provider that implements this specification and you're good to go.

Just to add the direct wiki link to the OneAPI MMS spec:     http://gsma.securespsite.com/access/Access%20API%20Wiki/MMS%20RESTful%20API.aspx and a link to the PHP/Java sandbox https://github.com/OneAPI/GSMA-OneAPI where MMS can be tested locally . Cheers.
```